# Problem with JQuery and rendering partial view in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have declared  an Action as follow :

```
public ActionResult EditComment(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                var comment = commentRepository.GetItem(id);

                return PartialView("Comment",comment);
            }
            catch
            {
                return Content("Error!");
            }
        }
```

And this is what I have in some view :

```
.....
<%:Html.ActionLink(GlobalText.Edit,"#", null, new { @class="EditLink",id=item.CommentID})%>
.....

<div id="link">

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.EditLink').click(function () {
            var idval = this.id;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Articles/EditComment",
                data: { id: idval },
                success: function (mydata) {
                    $("#link").empty().append(mydata);
                },
                type: "POST"
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

When I Click on a link with 'EditLink' Class, the application go through running action result, but '$("#link").empty().append(mydata);' of jquery does not work, and i get nothing!

Comment: instead of .empty().append(mydata); Why not just use .html(mydata); ?

Comment: Looks good to me... does the JS console have any errors  Also, you end that script tag, right?

Comment: 'John Kurlak ' >> yes I have ended it. and also I have fire-bug installed in my firefox, when I put a breakpoint in line containing the '$("#link").empty().append(mydata);' it does not stop there. 'Kahoun' >> it is not working

Comment: Also try adding dataType: 'html', to your ajax call.  Your code looks good, have you confirmed that there is data in mydata?

Comment: Can you confirm that the Action Method is being called? Also, why don't you use the load function instead of the ajax call?

Comment: yes, I also debugged my mvc application and I saw Action was running without any exception. Kahoun  >> still not working!

Comment: I checked firebug Net tab and saw an '500 Internal Server Error'. By getting deeper in error detail, I understand that the problem is with loading partial view template. Thanks every one.

Answer (score 0):

try to change `public ActionResult - to PartialResult EditComment(int id)`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $(".EditLink").each(function(){
         $(this).click(function () {
        var idval = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Articles/EditComment",
            data: { id: idval },
            success: function (mydata) {
                $("#link").empty().append(mydata);
            },
            type: "POST"
        })
     });
```

}

Comment: Because I am newbie to Jquery, would please tell me what should I use  instead of '$(document).' ?

Comment: I thought its from EditComment/ View.....your Problem is  you have to use .each() after selecting $('.EditLink')..... like this $('.EditLink').each(function(){this.click(......)})

Comment: devson - the above is not a good idea. the .EditLink 'class' definition already does this in the original code. bad bad :)